# Does $a^m \equiv 1\ (\text{ mod } n)$ solution exist for every integer where $(a,n)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For example, given the following modular equation:
$$7^m \equiv 1\ (\text{ mod } 13); \quad (7,13)=1$$
By hard working, we can find the solution:
$$7^{12} \equiv 1\ (\text{ mod } 13)$$

From my observation, the solution seems to exist for all $a,n \text{ where } (a,n)=1$.
But, I can't come up with any proof. So the question is,

Given integer $a, m, n$, where $(a,n)=1$, Is the following statement always solvable?

$$a^m \equiv 1\ (\text{ mod } n)$$

And if always true or for the true cases, given $a\text{ and }n$ what would be the practical way to find the solution? (Something better than brute-forcing all the values)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The easiest way to solve prove this is using pigeonhole principle - it implies $n$ must divide some difference $a^k-a^l=a^l(a^{k-l}-1)$ with $k>l$. Since $\gcd(a,n)=1$, $n\mid a^{k-l}-1$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html

Comment: Euler's theory says precisely that.

Comment: Ah... you seem to have stumbled onto Euler's Thereom entirely on your own.  I'm impressed!  Good job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is *Euler's theorem*:

> For any $a$ coprime with $n$, one has $$a^{\varphi (n)}\equiv 1\mod n,$$
>   where $\varphi$ is the totient function.

So the least $m$ such that $a^m\equiv 1\mod n$ (the `order` of $a$ modulo $n$) is a divisor of $\varphi(n)$.

*Note*: the value of the totient function is easy to calculate: if $n=p_1^{r_1}\dotsm p_k^{r_k}$ is the decomposition of $n$ as a product of distinct primes, then
$$\varphi(n)=p_1^{r_1-1}(p_1-1)\dotsm p_k^{r_k-1}(p_k-1).$$

Comment: Thanks! I'm so amazed that my question exactly resemble Euler's theorem!

Answer (score 4):

Since $a$ is relatively prime with $n$, it has an inverse modulo$~n$, a solution $s$ to $as\equiv 1\pmod n$. (If $s,t$ are Bézout coefficients such that $1=as+nt$, then $s$ is such an inverse.) This means that multiplication by $a$, as operation on the set of $n$ congruence classes modulo$~n$, has an inverse (multiplication by $s$), so it is a bijection. Then the sequence of classes modulo$~n$ of $1=a^0,a=a^1,a^2,a^3,\ldots$, which must ultimately encounter a class that is already present earlier in the sequence (as the stock of fresh classes is finite), must do this for the first time by hitting the class of $a^0$ (otherwise the class of first collision has two distinct predecessor classes, contradicting bijectivity). That is $a^m\equiv1\pmod n$ has a solution $m>0$.

Comment: What is a bijection?

Comment: @İbrahimİpek A bijection is an invertible map between two sets (or as is the case here, from a set to itself).

Comment: "...must do this for the first time by hitting the first class..." What does this have to do with bijection?

Comment: "*This means that multiplication by a, as operation on the set of n congruence classes modulo n, has an inverse (multiplication by s), so it is a bijection.*" I'm sorry but could you explain this further?

Comment: So first @Anakin, a map $m$ from a set $S$ to itself produces for every element $x$ of $S$ another element of $S$, written $m(s)$. In the example $m$ is multiplication by $a$: the map sends the class $x$ to the class $ax$ (strictly speaking, the class of some number $k$ in the class $x$ to the class $m(x)$ containing its multiple $ak$; a crucial point it that this is well defined: doesn't depend on which element $k$ in the class $x$ is chosen). Having an inverse operation means that there is some map that will undo this operation: applied to $m(x)$ it returns $x$. Here $y\mapsto sy$ does that.

Comment: So @İbrahimİpek, suppose $a^i\equiv a^j\pmod n$ is the first collision (meaning $i$ is the minimal possible, and for that $i$ the exponent $j>i$ is minimal). If $i>0$, we can apply the inverse operation $g$ of multiplying by $a$ to both sides of the congruence: $g(a^i)\equiv g(a^j)$ (we can do this because $g$ is well defined on congruence classes modulo$~n$). This means $a^{i-1}\equiv a^{j-1}\pmod n$, contradicting the minimality of $i$. So only $i=0$ is possible. Having the inverse operation $g$ is essential here; for a non-invertible operation like $\times2$ modulo $12$, the argument fails.

Comment: Simply put, you're saying that this operation is bijective and invertible, thus the solution exists. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @Anakin: Bijective and invertible is the same thing. Abstractly, the argument is: for any operation $f$ on a finite set and initial value $x$, there have to be $i<j$ with $f^i(x)=f^j(x)$ (the iterations of $f$ have to end up running in a circle). But if $f$ is invertible, then this moreover has to happen with $i=0$ (only repeating from the very start is possible), which means that $f^j(x)=x$ has a solution $j>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Such an $m$ always exists, and the least such $m$ always divides $\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi$ denotes Euler's totient function.

A nice way to prove this is by showing that the units of the ring $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ are precisely the classes of numbers coprime to $n$.

Comment: proving Fermat shows Euler, and the fact $1^n=1$ suffices.

Comment: @Servaes As the answer by Bernard indicates, you can only state that the *least* such $m$ divides $\varphi(n)$ instead of saying "always". However, you can state that this least such $m$ must divide any other $m$ which works.

Comment: @JohnOmielan You are right, I have corrected this.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?